# activemq memory limit configuration Vs maxPageSize

Tags: activemq-classic

I am unable to understand how the two attributes differ:'memoryLimit' and 'maxPageSize'

As per documentation:

'**maxPageSize**' = 'maximum number of persistent messages to page from store at a time'

'**memoryLimit**' - corresponds to the amount of memory that's assigned to the in-memory store for the queue

Here is a sample configuration for a queue :

```
<policyEntry queue="Consumer.normal.queue" producerFlowControl="true" memoryLimit="3200" maxPageSize="4" 
maxBrowsePageSize="1000" prioritizedMessages="true" useCache="false" expireMessagesPeriod="0" queuePrefetch="1">
```

what I have observed is that if the maxPageSize =1 and memoryLimit = "3200" then I can see 2 messages loaded into memory and can be browsed via a jms client ( rest of the messages get stored in kahadb )

however if the maxPageSize = 4 and memoryLimit = "3200" then I can see 4 messages loaded into memory and can be browsed via a jms client

So are the two values meant to serve the same purpose ?
AND
does it mean that whichever of the these two attributes provides the greater number of messages will be used by activemq ?

Comment: also tried with maxPageSize=8 and 16 keeping a constant value for memoryLimit=3200 and in both these cases could see 8 and 16 messages available in memory

Answer (score 2):

maxPageSize determines how many messages ActiveMQ loads from the store (in your case, KahaDB) to hand to consumers. The memoryLimit indicates how much memory to allocate to keep messages in memory.

In short, (message size x maxPageSize <= memoryLimit) so that you do not hit producer flow control.

You want your page size to be much higher than 1 or 2 for ActiveMQ to perform (200 to 1000 to start). Numbers that low will have higher latency.

Note: Priority is an anti-pattern in distributed messaging at significant load (over 1M messages per day). It works well in a local embedded broker within your Java VM process. ActiveMQ disables it by default.

To enable priority support, update the <destinationPolicy queue=".." and add this attribute: prioritizedMessages="true"

Comment: We need to implement priority of messages so that higher priority ( 9 ) messages are served to consumers hence we are trying to limit page size. Can you expand on your point regarding `producer flow control` ?

Comment: also if memory limit value is such that it can accomodate only 2 messages but everytime I can see that the number of messages loaded are driven by maxPageSize , so I am unable to understand how this is possible when memory limit is getting exceeded ?

Comment: Why do you want to use priority?  Priority is an anti-pattern with distributed messaging. If you need priority-- separate messages into different queues. ActiveMQ supports composite listening, so you can do session.createQueue("FOO.P9, FOO.P8,FOO.P7")  etc.. so the consumer gets all the messages for the queues and the P9 will generally be consumed quickly since its queue size should generally be lower